# Issue in UIActivityIndicatorView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, uiactivityindicatorview, presentmodalviewcontroller

Currently i am working in iphone app, Using UIWebView (Webpage shown in presentModelViewController) to show webpage on the screen, then i add UIActivityIndicatorView to show in load url request, but the UIActivityIndicatorView didn't show in the screen, i tried my level best, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activity.frame=CGRectMake(140, 240, 40, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:activity]; 

    web = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    web.delegate=self;
    web.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wrwr.rww.com/erqrrq"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:req];
    [self.view addSubview:web];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    [activity stopAnimating];  
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{     
    [activity startAnimating];   
}
```

Comment: Try adding the web view first and the activity view second, otherwise the web view could hide the activity view.

Comment: can you try to add your activity indicatore in to webview like : -[web addSubview:activity];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    web = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    web.delegate=self;
    web.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wrwr.rww.com/erqrrq"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:req];
    [self.view addSubview:web];

    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activity.frame=CGRectMake(140, 240, 40, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:activity];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:activity];
}
```

Comment: Please see the edit. Your code doesn't work because your activity indicator is hidden by the webview. Place activity indicator above web view and bring activity indicator to front can solve this. Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

adding your activitiy indicatore View in to your webView like this:-

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activity.frame=CGRectMake(140, 240, 40, 40);


web = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
web.delegate=self;
web.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wrwr.rww.com/erqrrq"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:req];
[web addSubview:activity];
[self.view addSubview:web];
}

 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
[activity stopAnimating];  
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{     
[activity startAnimating];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define UIActivityIndicatorView after defining UIWebView.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        web = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        web.delegate=self;
        web.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wrwr.rww.com/erqrrq"];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [web loadRequest:req];
        [self.view addSubview:web];

     activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        activity.frame=CGRectMake(140, 240, 40, 40);
        [self.view addSubview:activity]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The order you add the sub views to the super view is significant. The `UIActivityIndicatorView` gets added and then the `UIWebView` overlays it. If you add the UIWebView first, i.e

```
[self.view addSubview:web];
[self.view addSubview:activity];
```

the `UIActivityIndicatorView` will overlay the `UIWebView`.